# How to get download URL of multiple images uploaded using Android & Firebase

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I see similar questions on this site but most of the questions are related to fetching the download URL for a single uploaded image. Taking help from those posts, now I can get the download URL of a single image.

But I face a problem when I try to get download URL for multiple images uploaded together. I want to do three things...

**1. Select three images

  2. Upload them to Firebase Cloud Storage

  3. Get the URLs of the uploaded images and save them in an `ArrayList`.**

I can do the first two things successfully, but have not managed to achieve the third thing. When I click the "update" button, all images are perfectly stored in Cloud Storage, but show an error when requesting the download URL of all images.

Here is the code for when I click the "update" button:

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading .... ");
        progressDialog.show();

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Pictures");

        int uploadCount = 0;

        // imageList is an ArrayList<Uri> which holds the address of selected 3 images. 
        // imageAddress is an ArrayList<String> where I want to save all downloadUrls of images (each url is saved as a string).
        // imagePath is a StorageReference

        while(uploadCount < imageList.size()) {
            Log.d("UploadCount", uploadCount+"");
            Uri uri_Image = imageList.get(uploadCount); 
            imagePath = storageReference.child(uri_Image.getLastPathSegment());

            imagePath.putFile(uri_Image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    imagePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(newOnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Uri downloadUri = uri;
                            imageAddress.add(downloadUri.toString());
                            Log.d("ImageAddress Size: ", imageAddress.size()+"");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignOutActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }); //.............
            if(uploadCount == (imageList.size()-1)) {
                Log.d("Good", "HELLO HELLO");
                Toast.makeText(SignOutActivity.this, "Successfully Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                upload.setClickable(false);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else {
                Log.d("BAD", "NOT HELLO "+uploadCount);
            }
            uploadCount = uploadCount + 1;

        }
    }
});
```

Here is the error:

```
2020-02-15 17:02:26.945 28207-28735/com.example.practiceapplication E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
    Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2020-02-15 17:02:26.946 28207-28735/com.example.practiceapplication E/StorageException: {"error": {"code": 404, "message": "Not Found. Could not get object", "status": "GET_OBJECT"}}
    java.io.IOException: {"error": {"code": 404, "message": "Not Found. Could not get object", "status": "GET_OBJECT"}}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2020-02-15 17:02:30.712 28207-28207/com.example.practiceapplication D/ImageAddress Size:: 1
```

It will be very helpful to me if anyone tells me the correction. Thank you

Comment: That error message is saying that the file you referenced doesn't exist in storage

Answer (score 3):

Your code suffers from using a mix of local variables and shared global variables whilst dealing with asynchronous code and for loops.

In the code above, you use the global variables `imagePath`, `imageAddress` and `imageList` inside a for loop which ultimately is the key cause of that Exception.

#### Code breakdown

When you click the `upload` button, your code performs the following steps with errors shown in bold:

- Gets the first image's URI
- Updates the value of `imagePath` to point at that image's upload location
- Starts the upload of the first image
- **Logs `"NOT HELLO 0"`**
- Gets the second image's URI
- Updates the value of `imagePath` to point at that image's upload location
- Starts the upload of the second image
- **Logs `"NOT HELLO 1"`**
- Gets the third image's URI
- Updates the value of `imagePath` to point at that image's upload location
- Starts the upload of the third image
- **Logs `"HELLO HELLO"` and Toasts `"Successfully Uploaded"`** (not actually finished yet)
- *[a few moments later]*
- The first image finishes uploading
- The download URL of the **third image** is requested **(which throws the `StorageException`)**
- The second image finishes uploading
- The download URL of the **third image** is requested **(which throws another `StorageException`)**
- The third image finishes uploading
- The download URL of the third image is requested (and would work correctly)

#### Fixes

To fix this, the following things must be done:

- Use a local variable copy of `imageList`
- Use a local variable for `storageReference`
- Use a local variable for `imagePath`, and rename to `imageRef` to accurately reflect it's type
- Rename `imageAddress` to `imageAddressList` to accurately reflect it's type (recommended)
- Remove the `while()` loop and use a for iterator instead
- Disable the upload button immediately instead of at the end
- Upload each image and fetch the download URLs in parallel, without conflicting with each other
- Only display "Successfully uploaded" or "Upload failed" messages after the uploads have actually completed
- Update `imageAddressList` only once, rather than asynchronously.

To be done:

- Handle [activity lifecycle changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes)
- Tap into `currentUploadTask` and bind it to a view dialog/notification to show file upload progress
- Update the UI once all the uploads are done

#### Updated code

Note: This was typed free-hand - expect a few typos.

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading .... ");
        progressDialog.show();
        upload.setClickable(false); // disable upload button whilst uploading

        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Pictures");
        final List<Uri> clonedImageList = new ArrayList<>(imageList);

        imageList.clear(); // empty old list?
        int imageListSize = clonedImageList.size();

        List<Task<Uri>> uploadedImageUrlTasks = new ArrayList<>(imageListSize);

        for (Uri imageUri : clonedImageList) {
            final String imageFilename = imageUri.getLastPathSegment();
            Log.d("upload.onClick()", "Starting upload for \"" + imageFilename + "\"...");

            StorageReference imageRef = storageReference.child(imageFilename); // Warning: potential for collisions/overwrite
            UploadTask currentUploadTask = imageRef.putFile(imageUri);

            Task<Uri> currentUrlTask = currentUploadTask
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("upload.onClick()", "Upload for \"" + imageFilename + "\" failed!");
                            throw task.getException(); // rethrow any errors
                        }

                        Log.d("upload.onClick()", "Upload for \"" + imageFilename + "\" finished. Fetching download URL...");
                        return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                })
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Uri, Uri>() { // purely for logging to debug, recommended to remove
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("upload.onClick()", "Could not get download URL for \"" + imageFilename + "\"!");
                            throw task.getException(); // rethrow any errors
                        }

                        Log.d("upload.onClick()", "Download URL for \"" + imageFilename + "\" is \"" + task.getResult() + "\".");
                        return task.getResult();
                    }
                });

              uploadedImageUrlTasks.add(currentUrlTask);
        }

        // At this point, all the files are being uploaded in parallel
        // Each upload is tracked by the tasks in uploadedImageUrlTasks

        Tasks.whenAllComplete(uploadedImageUrlTasks)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<Uri>>>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull List<Task<Uri>> tasks) {
                    int tasksCount = tasks.size();
                    List<Uri> failedUploads = new ArrayList<>();
                    imageAddressList.clear(); // empty old entries?

                    for (Task<Uri> task : tasks) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            successCount++;
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                            imageAddressList.add(downloadUri.toString());
                        } else {
                            Uri imageUri = clonedImageList.get(tasks.indexOf(task));
                            failedUploads.add(imageUri);
                            Log.e("upload.onClick()", "Failed to upload/fetch URL for \"" + imageUri.getLastPathSegment() + "\" with exception", task.getException()); // log exception
                        }
                    }

                    progressDialog.dismiss(); // dismiss upload dialog

                    if (failedUploads.size() > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignOutActivity.this, failedUploads.size() + "/" + tasksCount + " uploads failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // TODO: Do something with list of failed uploads such as readd to the now empty upload list
                        imageList.addAll(failedUploads);
                        upload.setClickable(true);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignOutActivity.this, "Successfully uploaded all " + tasksCount + " files.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // TODO: Now that imageAddressList has been updated, update the UI - e.g tell recycler view to refresh
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I can understand clearly, but 
 Tasks.whenAllComplete(uploadedImageUrlTasks).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<Uri>>>() {@Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull List<Task<Uri>> tasks) {}
});........... IS NOT WORKING, it shows error, No error is shown when i write 

Tasks.whenAllComplete(uploadedImageUrlTasks).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<?>>>() {@Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Task<?>>> tasks) {}
});

But inside this, Uri downloadUri = task.getResult(); line shows error